# Unable to migrate from CommonsChunkPlugin to Webpack 4 optimization.splitChunks

Tags: webpack

I'm unable to figure out how to migrate my existing webpack 3 CommonsChunkPlugin to the new webpack 4 optimization.splitChunks.

My existing configuration can be distilled to the following:

```
module.exports = function (env) {
    const entry = {
        common: ['libA', 'libB', './common/A.js', './common/A.js', /* ... */],
        pageA: ['./src/pageA/file1.js', './src/pageA/file2.js', /* ... */],
        pageB: ['./src/pageB/file1.js', './src/pageB/file2.js', /* ... */],
        /* ... */
    };

    return {
        entry,
        output: {
            path: path.resolve('./dist'),
            filename: `[name]${env.mode === 'production' ? '.min' : ''}.js`,
            chunkFilename: `[name]${env.mode === 'production' ? '.min' : ''}.js`
        },
        module: {
            /* ... */
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: 'common',
                filename: `[name]${env.mode === 'production' ? '.min' : ''}.js`,
                chunks: Object.keys(entry),
                minChunks: 10
            })
        ]
    };
};
```

This generates a single common chunk named `common.min.js` that contains (at least) all files specified in the `common` entry and additionally adds all files that are used in at least 10 entries.

How would I do this in webpack 4 using `optimization.splitChunks`?

Comment: did you migrate success? @doberkofler

Comment: Yes, I‘m now on version 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar like this:

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            commons: {
                name: 'commons',                   
                minChunks: entries.length,
                chunks: 'initial'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would need to change the chunks to include your chosen chunks as I don't declare explicit modules as chunks, ie. I have no 'commons' entry point in entries like you do.